# How can I pull a specific IP from an NGIX server wordpress blog acces log

Tags: wordpress, apache, logging, nginx

This is a pretty specific question and I'm not too well versed with NGIX or Wordpress but heres the situation.

I'm trying to parse an access log file for an IP address tied to a specific form submission.

The form is located at the local path /about/ but looking in the logs I can't find any pages that match this request which I believe is due to wordpress routing system. The form  html looks like this

```
 <form action="/about/#wpcf7-f7730-p2-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">
 <div style="display: none;">
 <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="7730">
 <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="3.3.2">
 <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f7730-p2-o1">
 <input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="79e7f7dc53">
 </div>
 <p>Your Name (required)<br>
 <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" size="40">       </span> </p>
<p>Your Email (required)<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="text" name="your-email"   value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required  wpcf7-validates-as-email" size="40"></span> </p>
<p>Subject<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" size="40"></span> </p>
<p>Your Message<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" class="wpcf7-form-control  wpcf7-textarea" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></span> </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control  wpcf7-submit"><img class="ajax-loader" src="http://outoftheboxfood.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form- 7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden;"></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
</form>
```

I have the access log but don't know what to look for to find any submissions of this form.

Comment: I think the action link  `/about/#wpcf7-f7730-p2-o1`, which I guess is the same URL of the form, is what you should look for in the server's logs.

Answer (score 0):

Get another line from the access log so that you know how it looks like for another page. It might look something like /?p=3453 or just /page-slug without the following slash.

In the first case you'll have to find the id of the about page and then look for it in the log.

If you don't need automation in seeking the ip, you can use grep in the shell:

```
grep '/the-page-pattern' access.log
```